# How to subscribe to DOMContentLoaded event in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript2.0

I'm porting UI theme from angular 1 to 2. In 1-st version I have `$viewContentLoaded` event and I want remake it to angular 2.

I'm trying to use `@HostListener('DOMContentLoaded')`, but it doesn't work (without any errors).

How can I resolve it? Or what is the best approach to handle that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't, `DOMContentLoaded` was emitted long before the first component is created.

You can use

```
class AppComponent {
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // your code here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
export class AppComponent{

  @HostListener('document:DOMContentLoaded', ['$event'])
  onDomContentLoaded(event: Event) {
    console.log('DOMContentLoaded TODO: your logic');
  }

}
```